# image not stable in mouseover and mouseleave

Tags: jquery, html, css

so I have this part of code in my html:

```
<img id="id1" src="photo1" usemap="#ir" >
<img  src="photo2" id="id2"/>
<span>
<map name="ir" id="ir">    
<area alt="" title="my title" href="my link" shape="poly" coords="13,15,29,34,10,65,1,39,17,57,357,77,15,64" />    
</map>       
</span>
```

and I have lots of area which i didn't wrote them ..
 my css for this part is:

```
#id2 {display: none; opacity: 0.4;}
```

and the Jquery for this part:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('span').on('mouseover',function() {
    $('#id2').show();
}).on('mouseleave',function() {
    $('#id2').hide();
});
})
```

as you see I select part of a image to be a link and its going to show a different photo (with opacity) when mouse come over it, but it's doesn't work correct.
The photo that should appear when mouse come over is not stable and the link doesn't work properly.
I think the link and the image code are not work at the same time and just work one by one.

Comment: Where is the link in your code? Do you have some external CSS positioning photo2 on top of photo1 ?

Comment: two photo are totally in the same area and as you see the link is part of first photo and when mouse come on that area the photo while appear and its going to be clickable @Bellash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, try to use mouseenter/mouseleave instead, and use a hover event, which includes (mouseenter/mouseleave)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $img = $('#id2');
 $('span').hover(function() {
   $img.show();
 },function() {
   $img.hide();
});
```

If you use mouseover, opposite to it is mouseout (not mouselave), mouseleave is opposite to the mouseenter event.

The main difference between these two is that mouseenter/mouseleave doesn't bubble, but mouseover/mouseout do.

Moreover when using mouseover/mouseout on element that has child elements, when mouse goes to a child element, the parent triggers mouseout. So it looks like the mouse has left the parent, but it just moved into a child.